# What is the Oracle exp utility file format?

Tags: oracle

I want to export data from Oracle to another database (not Oracle).

Can I use `exp` utility to transfer data?

What is the file format of the `exp` utility output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to export data from Oracle to another database (not Oracle).

I'd say that the simplest way is to export data in CSV (text) format and load it into the target database using its (target database's) loading capabilities.

---

> Can I use exp utility to transfer data?

No, you can not. Export utility (whether older EXP/IMP or modern Data Pump) work only on Oracle databases, with certain restrictions. There's the *compatibility matrix* which shows which utility version is supported on which database version. Generally speaking, export data using source database version's export utility and import data using target database version's import utility, but you can't e.g. export 19c and import it into 8i; that won't work.

---

> What is the file format of the exp utility output?

Proprietary. I'm not sure Oracle revealed it to public.